# Ubuntu One can't connect after installing CouchDB

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

I've used with UbuntuOne on Ubuntu 10.04 (both 32- and 64-bit on different computers) and it worked very well until one month ago. Then I wanted to try to sync my contacts too, so I installed CouchDB from backport repository as described in the official guide for UbuntuOne; after that UbuntuOne doesn't sync or connect anymore.

So read a lot of forums and guides and I've reinstalled UbuntuOne client and now the client can't connect or login (even if I clear password from keymanager). 
I've used the ubuntuone-preferences, u1tools and u1sync... but nothing.
When I enter just the `u1tool` command in the terminal (with any option), this appears:

`Oops, an error ocurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1`

Any Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to this?

**1)** Remove any backport repository you may have added.

**2)** Run this at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude purge ubuntuone-client && sudo aptitude install ubuntuone-client
```